# How to install specific pod without touching other dependencies

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I want to install specific dependency using `cocoapods`. if I execute `pod install`, other dependencies are getting updated before installing my newly added dependency. I just want to install specific pod without touching any others. And I know `deleting`, `updating` any dependency also updates others. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Actually my problem is when I myself modify some dependency ([AFNetworking](http://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for example) and run `pod install` it reverts back to its original version. But I don't want to lose my changes.

Comment: What dependency are you updating? I would make it so my project can take future pod install commands.

Comment: pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.2.1". In this dependency I mad changes by myself, and added another dependency to the project. When I run pod install my changes in AFNetworking are loosing

Comment: @ShamsiddinSaidov, why do you want to modify a pod? It's not a good practice (exactly because of difficulties with updates). If you really need it, the better approach is to fork AFNetworking, modify your own fork, and install your fork instead of the original AFNetworking library. I saw a question about it here somewhere several days ago.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but anyway If I don't want to update my existing pods what is the solution? Say my project works with the old version of the pod and it shouldn't update to the new one?

Comment: @ShamsiddinSaidov, you could write the version explicitly like so: `pod 'AFNetworking', '2.2.1'`

Comment: :) ok. I'll fork the AFNetworking. Seems it's the best solution.

Comment: Hey @ShamsiddinSaidov, Did get any solution for this?

Comment: @Yuyutsu, I didn't do anything. But if you have this problem I think you need to follow FreeNickname's above mentioned solutions.

Comment: @ShamsiddinSaidov, Yes, I did that same :)

Answer (score 54):

To Skip running pod repo update before install.Use

```
pod install --no-repo-update
```

Comment: This still update the other pods as I was trying to skip updation of other pods that were that for xcode 8.3.3 and now after migration to xcode 9 they didn't get converted like in previous xcode versions.

Answer (score 43):

**To install a plugin without updating existing ones-> Add that plugin in your Podfile and use:**

```
pod install --no-repo-update
```

**To remove/update a specific plugin use:**

```
pod update POD_NAME
```

Tested!

Comment: Seems a little strange at first, but this works as **atulkhatri** mentioned when removing a single library. Remove the item from your pod file and run update `podname`.

Comment: @skymook not working for me to remove FacebooCore library :(

Comment: @Niki I have same problem with 'FacebookCore'. Have you find any solution?

Comment: @YogendraPatel It is possible that some other third-party framework has added on older version of Facebook SDK as a dependency. Could you please check your `Podfile.lock` to see if that is not the case?

Comment: This still seems to meddle with the other Pods already installed.

Comment: @HashimAkhtar If more than 1 pod rely on the same framework, it might be a good idea to update both of them to avoid incompatibility.

Comment: `pod update POD_NAME` which is also not working; It is updating other pods.

Answer (score 26):

1) If you want to update single pod

**pod update 'yourpodname'**

2) if you want to install one pod without affecting another pod

**pod install --no-repo-update**

3)if you want to install/update specific version of pod

**pod 'Stripe', '3.0'**

4) if you want to install/update latest version of pod than

**pod 'KCFloatingActionButton'**

Comment: `pod install --no-repo-update` is out dated, not working.... Is there any other solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here you can skip integration of the Pods libraries in the Xcode project(s) by using following command.

```
pod install --no-repo-update
```

[Pod install](http://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_install)

Hope this help you.

Comment: @Shamsiddin Saidov, this command only add new pod that is not integrate earlier.

Comment: It didn't help. `pod install --no-repo-update` also updating existing pods

Comment: I have AFNetworking integrated in my project and I modified some classes in it. When I added another pod, say pod `'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 4.1'` and run `pod install --no-integrate` it reverts back my modified AFNetworking classes to it's original version. I.e. it's updating my already installed dependencies before installing `Facebook-iOS-SDK`

Comment: --no-integrate is out of date.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing, pod install will only install pods in the PodFile that haven't already been installed.  The others will not be updated.  This issue appears to have been solved by the CocoaPods project.

Comment: this doesnt seem to be the case when there is a major revision update for Cocoapods itself... i.e. Version 1.0.0 was release just recently but because its a major version evidently it tries to update all pods to the latest , even when specifying otherwise int he command line - at least thats what happened in my case

Answer (score 0):

Do not get confused just open up the existing file and added the numbers of pod file below the existing pods.

Further, go to terminal and open up your project and run command:

$ pod install

(This command will only add on the new pod without disturbing your existing pods)

Answer (score 0):

```
pod repo update && pod update 'YOURPOD'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have your first "Podfile.lock" in your project folder, you just have to use

```
pod install
```

Your "Podfile.lock" has registered the version of your old pod so you don't need to do something else

Comment: That's not what the OP had asked. The question is how to install only a newly added POD in the podfile instead of updating ALL the pods from repo which `pod install` does.

Answer (score -2):

Here is another way of doing it. If you want to install newly added pod and don't want to update other dependancies you need to remove "**~>**" from all your pods you don't want to update. 
For example in case of AFNetworking

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '2.2.1'   instead of pod 'AFNetworking',~> '2.2.1'
```