# How to remove specific pod without touching other dependencies

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I want to remove specific dependency using cocoapods. if I execute pod install, other dependencies are getting updated before removing the dependency I want to delete. I just want to remove specific pod without touching any others. And I know deleting, updating any dependency also updates others. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Actually my problem is when I modify some dependency (AFNetworking for example) and run pod install it reverts back to its original version. But I don't want to lose my changes.

Comment: Cocoapod auto generate a Podfile.lock keep all framework's version. When you run pod install, it doesn't update the framework's version.

Comment: But I modified one dependency and when I run a command like pod install it revert back the changes I made to the original source code of the pod

Comment: In your case, you should fork the repo to your repo and edit. In the cocoapods file, add options to your edited repo

Comment: @PabloMarrufo check my answer it is working.

Comment: please look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372294/how-to-install-specific-pod-without-touching-other-dependencies

Comment: What do you mean by "I myself modify some dependency"??

Comment: @Bilal it was a typo hahah

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Remove specific pod from `podfile` and run below command in terminal:

```
pod install --no-repo-update
```

[image]

Comment: This solution correctly deleted the pod folders from the hard drive, whereas `pod install` on its own removed the pods from Xcode but often left the files in the project folder.

Comment: For Apple M1 chip MacBook I have used 'arch -x86_64 pod install --no-repo-update'.

Comment: It also updating existing pods, not working....

Answer (score -2):

[image: Remove specific pod]

pictorial representation with steps detailed.